# how to inherit android style for changing the image src?

Tags: android

i want to inherit android style just want to override the android:src property ?

`<style name="headerLeftSideImageStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_back</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentLeft">true</item>
        <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can inherit styles. PLease refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 2):

```
 <style name="GreenText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    </style>
```

through this you can inherit the styles

or u can use the default themes of android as mentioned in this [Link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml)